# What sort of gestures that come from the Android API can I translate to a computer using the Java robot class?

Tags: java, android, gestures, pinchzoom, awtrobot

I know that mouse movement, clicks, keyboard presses etc. can be translated to the robot class but is it possible to link gestures, specifically the two finger zoom?

For context i'm making an android app and desktop app that uses the mouses to translate mouse movement/clicks/gestures to the desktop computer via bluetooth.

Comment: There is no `Robot` class in the Android SDK.

Comment: You're misunderstanding me. Ignore essentially the android part of this question. How can I use the robot class in JAVA to emulate the pinch to zoom effect that you can do on Android phones.